# Website Redirect error (Entering infinite loop)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect the traffic in my website from

**example.com/anything**     to   **example.com/search/anything**

Such that **example.com/sandy**  would  go to **example.com/search/sandy**

I have tried the below redirects in the `.htaccess` file. But, it is either entering "infinite loop" or getting a browser error message:

> "The page isn't redirecting properly"

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*) http://www.example.com/directsearch/$1

RedirectMatch 301 /$ http://www.example.com/directsearch/$1
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+directsearch/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /directsearch/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply anubhava.

But, now, its getting redirected to the below URL infinitely:
>www.example.com/directsearch/sandy?/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/directsearch/sandy&/sandy

Comment: Looks still the same(except that the name sandy now got shifted to the last):  http://www.addressid.in/directsearch/index.php?/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/index.php&/directsearch/sandy&/sandy

Comment: Where is `index.php` coming from? Do you have other rules also? Make sure this is first line in your htaccess and you test it after totally clearing browser cache.

Comment: Cool...Looks better now @anubhava....When i commented out remaining rules and used only the rule you gave, it got redirected successfully as needed...Thanks a lot man....But, when I kept the other rule, it again went to infinite loop. Do you see if there any way that I can keep both your rule and one more rule (shown below) ?  My file is as below:

RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
  RedirectMatch 301 ^/(?!directsearch/)(.*)$ /directsearch/$1
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Done..Thanks again :)